# Matrix Norm With Respect to Another Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, definition, normed-spaces

I'm reading through a book on numerical analysis right now and in its treatment of linear iterative method the author takes the norm of a  matrix with respect to another matrix but never seems to say what this actually means.

For a little more context we are dealing with iterative methods of the form $x^{(k + 1)} = Bx^{(k)} + f$ to solve $Ax = b$, then splitting $A = P - N$ where $P$ is suitably nice and $B = P^{-1}N$. Then the author makes guarantees on the spectral radius of $B$ given certain criteria on $A$ and $P$ and states during this:

$$\rho(B) = \Vert B \Vert_A = \Vert B \Vert_P < 1$$

Perhaps it is the induced norm of $\Vert \cdot \Vert_A$, ie.

$$\Vert B \Vert_A = \sup_{\Vert x \Vert_A = 1} \frac{(Bx)^TA(Bx)}{x^TAx}?$$

What does $\Vert \cdot \Vert_A$ with respect to another matrix mean?

Comment: ... or perhaps $\lVert X\rVert_A=\lVert AXA^{-1}\rVert$.

Answer (score 1):

This is called an "elliptical" norm, or the Euclidean norm relative to the scalar product defined by $A$. Which obviously demands that $A$ is s.p.d.

The unit sphere of the $A$ norm is an ellipsoid in standard Euclidean coordinates, thus the name.

Note that your formula defines $\|B\|_A^2$.

Comment: Sounds interesting, where could I find a little more information about them? A quick google search yielded few results.

Comment: I can imagine that this falls generally under "operator norms in Hilbert spaces". One standard result where this is mentioned explicitly is that for every matrix of an endomorphism and $\epsilon>0$ there is a scalar product so that the operator norm is $\epsilon$-close to the spectral radius. I'm currently not sure if that directly implies the equality that you cite in the question, as the coefficients of the scalar products are not necessarily bounded.